# Typescript error when using custom palette color with Chip component in MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a custom theme where I've added custom colors to the palette. My hope was that the color prop would work with a custom color. I tested with the Button component and it worked fine. However when I tried to do the same with the Chip component I received a TypeScript error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
```

And this is what my theme looks like:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    slate: {
      darker: "#11161A",
      dark: "#1F2932",
      main: "#2E3D49",
      light: "#6D7780",
      lighter: "#B4B9BD",
      lightest: "#F7F7F8",
    }
  }
});

export default theme;

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface PaletteColor {
    lightest?: string;
    lighter?: string;
    darker?: string;
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    slate: any;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material/Button" {
  interface ButtonPropsColorOverrides {
    slate: true;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material/Chip" {
  interface ChipPropsColorOverrides {
    slate: true;
  }
}
```

And ideas?

Comment: Your codesandbox doesn't have anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `contrastText` in your custom color. From the [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/Chip/Chip.js#L154), when the `Chip` color is not `default`, it uses the `theme.palette[chipColorProp].main` for background color and `theme.palette[chipColorProp].contrastText` for foreground color:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    slate: {
      darker: '#11161A',
      dark: '#1F2932',
      main: '#2E3D49',
      light: '#6D7780',
      lighter: '#B4B9BD',
      lightest: '#F7F7F8',
      contrastText: '#ffffff', // <------------------ Add this line to fix
    },
  },
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]